# Python BeautifulSoup: How to Find Last Occurrence of Tag with Specific Attribute

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

How can you find the last occurrence of a tag with this attribute: `data-index` without having the value of it?

I have written the code below but it returns `IndexError: list index out of range` although the list is not empty.

```py
soup.find_all(attrs={"data-index"})[-1]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What element do you wanna find? (tr, span, div, a....) I found this on my code: soup.find_all("tr", {"id": True}). So maybe you can try, replace "tr" for your element, and "id" with "data-index"

Comment: Is there an url to test with? There may be alternative ways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the set `attrs={"data-index"}` to dict `attrs={"data-index":True}`:

```
data = '''<div>
 <div>
   <div data-index="1">xxx</div>
 </div>

 <div>
   <div data-index="2">xxx</div>
 </div>

 <div>
   <div data-index="3">xxx</div>
 </div>
</div>
'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')
print(soup.find_all(attrs={"data-index":True})[-1])
```

Prints:

```
<div data-index="3">xxx</div>
```

---

Or with CSS selectors:

```
print(soup.select('[data-index]')[-1])
```